Flutter Plugin >> iOS >> Adding Privacy Manifest to 3rd party library
I maintain a Flutter plugin that is written in Flutter and acts as a wrapper for a native SDK on Android and iOS. I've recently been working on updating the native SDK to its most current version. On the iOS side, a Privacy Manifest is integrated within the native SDK itself. However, when I use the plugin and run a privacy report in my Flutter app, the report indicates that there's no Privacy Manifest present even though it's included in the underlying native SDK.
My query is regarding the proper method for incorporating this privacy manifest (PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy) into the Flutter plugin. Given that the native iOS SDK, which our plugin depends on, already contains a Privacy Manifest, what would be the correct approach here?
Should I create a separate PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file specifically for the plugin, and then specify it in the plugin's .podspec file using s.resource_bundle, like so:
s.resource_bundles = { 'MySDKPrivacy' => ['path/to/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy'] }

Is this the recommended course of action, or is there another preferred way to ensure the Privacy Manifest is recognized in the context of the Flutter plugin?
Thank you in advance for your guidance.
I updated to the latest SDK versions -> generated a Privacy report and got that the report is empty becase the privacy manifest is not included.

Update: I created the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy in the Android Studio within the iOS folder -> Resources folder -> PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy. ran pod update, and it worked, but if there is a better solution, that would be great because I think it's redundant when I just copy-pasted it twice...
